# Javascript - dont compare if condition met

Tags: javascript

I have this script for my html table which colors the cells in column row by row:

```
$(document).ready( function () {

        var table, aP, rtvP, mmP, meP;
        table = document.getElementById('productTable');

        for (i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {

            var rowCells = table.rows.item(i).cells;
            if (rowCells[3].firstChild.data !== '—') {
                aP = parseFloat(rowCells[3].firstChild.data);
            } else {
                aP = 0;
            }
            if (rowCells[5].firstChild.data !== '—') {
                rtvP = parseFloat(rowCells[5].firstChild.data);
            } else {
                rtvP = 0;
            }
            if (rowCells[7].firstChild.data !== '—') {
                mmP = parseFloat(rowCells[7].firstChild.data);
            } else {
                mmP = 0;
            }
            if (rowCells[9].firstChild.data !== '—') {
                meP = parseFloat(rowCells[9].firstChild.data);
            } else {
                meP = 0;
            }
            console.log(aP, rtvP, mmP, meP);

            if (aP > rtvP || mmP || meP) {
                rowCells[3].bgColor = 'red';
            } else if (aP === rtvP || mmP || meP) {
                rowCells[3].bgColor = 'yellow';
            } else {
                rowCells[3].bgColor = 'green';

            }


        }

    })
```

I know that is a little monster, but the only thing I miss is that, there should be no comparison for value if that value = 0. Ex. If aP = 100, rtvP = 150, mmP = 0, meP = 50, value of mmP should be skipped in comparison. Is there easy way to do that? I don't want to make another spaghetti of IFs

Comment: It's time to learn about loops, arrays and functions because this code is full of ridiculous amounts of repetition. Not only does that help simplify your code and make it more maintainable, it helps us understand it better.

Comment: I know that it's very bad, but I use it for just that one thing in my django project. I'm not even a begginer in js.

Comment: It's functional, just messy. I'm only saying this because it's important to practice how to modularize your code so you don't drown in it and end up discouraged by how hard it gets. Keeping things organized is an essential programming skill, and it's not hard, just takes discipline.

Comment: I learned it the hard way in python.

Comment: Do you intend `aP === rtvP || mmP || meP` to mean "`aP` is equal to *one of* the values `rtvP`,`mmp` or `meP`" or "`aP` is equal to `rtvP`, or either of `mmp` or `meP` is non-zero?"

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lazkx9ww/5/

Do you mean something like this? I'm sorry I'm quite confused by your question, which is why I'm commenting instead of answering

Comment: I would try to `forEach do..while`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try converting one of those instances to a proper function:

```
function convertP(value) {
   if (value !== '—') {
     return parseFloat(value);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Then you can call it like:

```
meP = convertP(rowCells[9].firstChild.data);
```

Where you can augment that `convertP` function to be "smarter" and handle different cases later.

Now for your comparison problem you probably want to store these converted values into an array instead of as a bunch of unrelated variables, like:

```
var points = [ ];

[ 3, 5, 7, 9 ].forEach(function(i) {
  points.push(convertP(rowCells[i].firstChild.data));
});
```

Where now you have all of them in one neat, tidy container. You can then compare them quickly by doing something like:

```
var diffs = [ ];
points.forEach(function(p) {
  diffs.push(aP - p);
});
```

The key thing to remember here is that floating point values are often *approximations* so it's important to not depend on them being precisely equal. 1.0 + 2.0 does not necessarily `===` 3.0. There's going to be a tiny amount of deviation due to floating point quirks, so go with +/- some tiny value, even if that value is 0.000001.

Now you can identify your color condition with a function:

```
function colorCondition(aP, points) {
  var state = 'green';
  var epsilon = 0.000001;

  points.forEach(function(p) {
    if (aP > (p + epsilon)) {
      state = 'red';
    }
    else if (aP > (p - epsilon)) {
      state = 'yellow';
    }
  });

  return state;
}
```

Now you have a generic solution that can work with *N* inputs. This is the goal of programming when you're trying to adhere to the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule).

Comment: It still not works like I want, but I'll accept that answer because it pushed me in the right way of doing that. There is still problem with comparison. aP is always > 0, and if rtvP, mmP or meP are 0 then state is always red, they should be red, only if any of them are greater than aP

Comment: @Wakun just change that last foreach loop's if statements to fit your colour pattern.

Comment: Thanks. I just filtered all 0 values from points array and adding condition if array is empty, then state = green. Now it works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways to put a prerequisite condition in *if* is using the logical *AND* operator: `&&`.

For your variables it will be something like:

`if (mmP!=0 && mmP>aP){}`

This way if mmP is 0, first condition will return false and second condition won't be processed.

You can enforce a condition without making another spaghetti of IFs.

I'm not sure I understood your use case, so if that does not work for you just comment it.